# Message156 Incorect Syntax Near the Keyword 'Join" / SQL Server (and which join?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

```
   SELECT *
    FROM
        (SELECT *
                FROM  Dim_Placement pl
                 OUTER JOIN 
                 Fact_Media_KPI j1
                 ON pl.SK_Placement_ID = j1.FK_SK_Placement_ID
            ) a1 
             OUTER JOIN
             (SELECT j1.*, pa.Package_Type, pa.Placement_Type, pa.Cost_Method, pa.Package_Name, pa.Package_Start_Date, pa.Package_End_Date,pa.Unit_Amount,pa.Unit_Rate,pa.Unit_Type
                 FROM  Dim_Package pa
                 OUTER JOIN
                 Fact_Media_KPI j1
                 ON pl.SK_Package_ID = j1.FK_SK_Package_ID) a2
                 ON a1.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID = a2.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID ) b1

       OUTER JOIN

         (SELECT j1.*, b.Brand_Name, b.Op_Co, b.Category
              FROM  Dim_Brand b
              OUTER JOIN 
              Fact_Media_KPI j1
              ON pl.SK_Brand_ID = j1.FK_SK_Brand_ID
             ) a3
         OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT j1.*, c.Budget_Campaign_Code, c.Campaign_Start_Date, c.Campaign_End_Date, c.Campaign_Status
            FROM  Dim_Campaign c
            OUTER JOIN 
            Fact_Media_KPI j1
            ON pl.SK_Campaign_ID = j1.FK_SK_Campaign_ID
            ) a4
         ON a3.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID = a4.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID) b2

    ON b1.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID = b2.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID) c1

    OUTER JOIN

        (SELECT j1.*, s.Site_Name
            FROM  Dim_Site s
            OUTER JOIN
            Fact_Media_KPI j1
            ON pl.SK_Site_ID = j1.FK_SK_Site_ID
            ) a5
       OUTER JOIN

       (SELECT j1.*,c.Creative_Adname, c.Creative_Filename, c.Click_Through_URL, c.Creative_ID, c.Creative_Size c.Creative_Type, c.Video_Length
           FROM  Dim_Creative c
           OUTER JOIN
           Fact_Media_KPI j1
           ON pl.SK_Site_ID = j1.FK_SK_Site_ID
           ) a6
        ON a5.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID = a6.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID) b3

        OUTER JOIN

        (SELECT j1.*, d.Date
           FROM  Dim_Site s
            OUTER JOIN
            Fact_Media_KPI j1
            ON pl.SK_Date_ID = j1.FK_SK_Date_ID
            ) a7
        ON b3.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID = a7.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID) c2
   ON c1.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID = c2.SK_Fact_MEDIAKPI_ID
   WHERE d.Date >= '2015-01-01';
```

The spacing has gotten god awful too. What went wrong - with this many Joins, that error is mostly meaningless.

I'm getting an error known as the 156 error - syntax error near a JOIN

One problem - which join?

As far as I can tell, it is legitimate to do nested dependent subqueries. Ideas?

(also, this size, is making it difficult for me to post.  Why stack why?)

Comment: Missing join-conditions (ON clauses), e.g. just after a5.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying `OUTER JOIN` only for your `JOIN`s, but you need to specify what type.  They can be either `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, or `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Please see this post for more information on the different `OUTER JOIN` types: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: In this particular case, I suspect a LEFT OUTER JOIN is most likely what is wanted.